# Запятая перед "что" (ПГ)

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, спп

Подскажите, нужна ли запятая в следующем предложении?

**Интересно(,) что он и сам не мог не знать об этом.**

Comment: Что такое ПГ? Нашел: пожарный гидрант , PowerGaming, 
правый глаз, почечная гиперкальциурия, парниковые газы,  патрульная группа, пакерующий гель, парогенератор.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да, запятая, безусловно, нужна — после слова "интересно" начинается придаточная часть сложноподчиненного предложения.

> Интересно, что он и сам не мог не знать об этом.

Answer (score -2):

Она обязательна, поскольку запятая требуется всегда в сложных предложениях: и в сложноподчинённых, и в сложносочинённых.